# running nodejs non root

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu

I have added a line to `/etc/rc.local` that starts a node process after reboot:

```
/usr/local/bin/node /home/ubuntu/app/index.js &
```

the problem is that the process is running as `root`.

How can I specify non-root user to run the node process as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this, but I haven't tested it in your context:

```
exec sudo -u nodejs /usr/local/bin/node /home/ubuntu/app/index.js &
```

Answer (score 1):

Telling the system to run your process as a different user than root would be a question more suitable for the Ubuntu Forums or the [Unix SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) site.

As to how to change the user to a non-privileged user from within the Node.js process, you can use [`process.setuid()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_setuid_id) and [`process.setgid()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_setgid_id) to change the user and group IDs, respectively.

Note that once you change these to non-root values, you cannot go back to the elevated root privileges.

Answer (score 1):

You can run it with another user with this line:

```
su -c "/usr/local/bin/node /home/ubuntu/app/index.js" & -s /bin/sh <username>
```

Comment: that looks like it should work, but when I do `ps aux | grep node` I can see that the process is still running as root even though the command I entered ordered it to start as the user `ubuntu`, is this expected?

Comment: Can you try to let node access a file that only root should have access to? It shouldn't work. @neo112

Comment: it breaks down into 2 different commands, first it tries to start the node process which succeeds (but as root) and then it tries to use the shell as another user after that but that fails: `-s: command not found`.
I tried to play around with the order of the -c and -s parameters but did not have success, can you detect what might be out of order?